# asp.net project installer (Install, creat and fill the database, copy pages and dlls)

Tags: asp.net, iis, installation, web-deployment

I have an asp.net project, and i want to create an installer for the deployment of the project. The installer will check if Sql Server is installed in the server, and if not, it will install it. The installer will also create and fill the database, and finally, it will create an repertory and copy the web pages and the dlls, and create the web site in IIS.

I have no idea how to do all this. So, can you just give the steps to follow.

(the deployment will be on a local server)

Thank you.

Comment: Step 1 : Google it.  Step 2 : Google it.  Step 3 : Google it. Step 4 : Go back to step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using installer specialized tools like "InstallShield" or "Advanced Installer". Both tools have dedicated support for this type of setup  configuration.

Comment: with Advanced Installer: - install  website: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-deploy-web-site-iis.html

Comment: with Advanced Installer - install SQL Express http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html

Comment: You can probably do this with Wix Toolset, which is free, but it will take you some time to learn the tool.